# How to "purge" oscillators

Tags: web-audio-api

If I trigger too many oscillators eventually newly triggered ones distort even if the oscillators are triggered one at a time and are not overlapping. Is there any command or pattern people are using to just 'purge' the oscillators that have been triggered in the background that are not playing anymore.

If there is another solution to this problem please post it as I might be approaching it wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the oscillators are stop()ed, and their mere previous incarnation is overloading the system?  I'd like to debug more - got a demo page?

Comment: Kind of. I made a node app locally and pushed it to github. Most of the code of the app is in the client. https://github.com/wktdev/nodesynthpad  main code is here  https://github.com/wktdev/nodesynthpad/blob/master/public/javascripts/synth.js